# ItemsControl databinding doesn't work?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have this WPF structure:

```
<UserControl 
      xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:..ViewModel.ToneAudiogramLegend">
      ...
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:ToneAudiogramLegendTableViewModel}">
      ...

    <DataGrid  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding ToneAudiogramLegneds}" HeadersVisibility="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0"
                                   MinWidth="100" Height="{Binding Height, Mode=OneWay}" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="None" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" GridLinesVisibility="None" ColumnWidth="*"
                                  Margin="1" wpfmvvm:DataGridRowHeightBehaviour.AutoFitRowHeight="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn HeaderTemplate="{x:Null}">
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Label x:Name="PART_Content" Content="{Binding Path=Left.Content}" 
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                            Foreground="Gold"/>

                                            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsMonochrome}" Value="True">
                                                   <Setter TargetName="PART_Content" Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
                                                  </DataTrigger>
                                            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
  ...
  <DataTemplate>
```

The binding of the `Value` works because the color gets the default value of `Left.Color` of `<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=Left.Color}"/>`

The `IsMonochrome` property changes value when a specific event occurs, but the Foreground color does not change to green. I am not quite sure the format and the structure is appropriate. I am not sure if `<DataTemplate>` is a problem, since I have another `<DataTemplate>` in higher order

The classes:

```
public partial class ToneAudiogramLegendTableViewModel : ViewModelBase, IToneAudiogramLegendTableViewModel, IHandleMonochromeReportElement
{
    public bool IsMonochrome
            {
                get { return GetValue<bool>("IsMonochrome"); }
                private set { SetValue("IsMonochrome", value); }
            }

            public void SwitchToMonochromeMode()
            {
                IsMonochrome = true;
            }

            public void SwitchToColorMode()
            {
                IsMonochrome = false;
            }
}
```

and

```
public class ToneAudiogramLegendViewModel : ViewModelBase, IToneAudiogramLegendVM
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get { return GetValue<string>("Name"); }
            set { SetValue("Name", value); }
        }

        public LegendViewModel Left
        {
            get { return GetValue<LegendViewModel>("Left"); }
            set { SetValue("Left", value); }
        }
}
```

and

```
public class LegendViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public object Content
        {
            get { return GetValue<object>("Content"); }
            set { SetValue("Content", value); }
        }

        public Brush Color
        {
            get { return GetValue<Brush>("Color"); }
            set { SetValue("Color", value); }
        }

        public LegendViewModel(object content, Brush color)
        {
            Content = content;
            Color = color;
        }
    }
```

What might be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your CellTemplate you are binding to `ToneAudiogramLegendViewModel` object, where are properties `Name` and `Left`. The `IsMonochrome` is on different object, that's why it does not work.

You need to either define IsMonochrome property or you need create property to reference `ToneAudiogramLegendTableViewModel` in  ToneAudiogramLegendViewModel to be able to databind to `IsMonochrome`.

**EDIT:**
based on your comments:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DataContext.IsMonochrome, 
                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource DataGrid}}" 
             Value="True">
```

Comment: The use of Label works, because the contents are displayed as it was with ContentPresenter. However the DataTrigger does not work. I just saw that because DataTemplate hadn't a reference to my c# class, the isMonochrome couldn't be referenced (I tested using the suggestions to Path). Even though I referenced it, it still can't change color when event occurs. Can I test this manually instead of binding? I just want to test out if the datatrigger works. I feel it never sees `<DataTemplate.Triggers>` but only the default value specified with `Path=LeftColor`

Comment: 1. can you check output window in visual studio while debugging if there are any binding errors? 2. Remove the foreground binding from label and leave trigger only to isolate the problem.

Comment: 3. where is the `IsMonochrome` property defined? it is the same object where `Left` property is defined? maybe you need `{Binding Path=Left.IsMonochrome}` in your datatrigger

Comment: I'm not sure how I can check the binding errors. I know the IsMonochrome gets changed the value when I press a button that triggers the event. I have removed the binding from the foreground and it has another color, which is different from the standard default `Left.Color`. I think you might have found the failure because the `Left` element and the `IsMonochrome` element is defined different places. The question is how to fix it?

Comment: can you post classes, where Left property and IsMonochrome property is defined? Just the classes definitions with properties, you can omit mehtods, field etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84376/discussion-between-ot0-and-liero).

Comment: I have inserted the IsMonochrome property inside `ToneAudiogramLegendViewModel` and it still not works. Note the `ItemsSource` in the upper tag `DataGrid` references to the property `ToneAudiogramLegneds`, which is defined as a list of ObservableCollections of `LegendViewModel` objects.

Comment: Your last edit: Exactly,I was going to give an answer for the problem before I saw your last edit.